# OpenCV Assertion failed - convertTo

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, vector, svm

I'm trying to convert my matrix into CV_32FC1 to train my SVM.I always get the error msg:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (func != 0) in convertTo, file /opt/opencv/modules/core/src/convert.cpp, line 1115
/eropt/opencv/modules/core/src/convert.cpp:1115: error: (-215) func != 0 in function convtTo
```

Basically I'm trying to

```
Mat eyes_train_data = Mat::zeros(Eyes.features.size(), CV_32FC1);
Eyes.features.copyTo(eyes_train_data);
eyes_train_data.convertTo(eyes_train_data, CV_32FC1);
```

I already tried to get the depth() of the matrix which returns `7`. I'm not sure what that means. the `Eyes.features` matrix is a (or should be) a floating-point matrix

to get the `Eyes.features` i use a gotHogFeatures-Method with

```
    vector<float> descriptorsValues;
    vector<Point> location;
    for( Mat patch : patches) {
      hog.compute( patch, descriptorsValues, Size(0,0), Size(0,0),   location);
        features.push_back(descriptorsValues); 
 }
```

descriptorValues represents a row vector and features should than look like:

```
features: 
{
descriptorValues0
descriptorValues1
...
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: what is Eyes.type()?

Comment: Eyes.features is type Mat; Eyes is just the typedef struct TrainingData Eyes

Comment: and Eyes.features.type() results to `7`

Comment: can you try to convert to CV_64FC1? maybe conversion fails if the source already has the desired type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conversion code doesn't seems right.
It should be something like:

```
Mat eyes_train_data;
eyes_train_data.convertTo(eyes_train_data, CV_32FC1);
```

What's the type of `Eyes.features`?
It seems that it should be already a `Mat1f`. However, are you sure that `features.push_back` works as expected? It seems that `push_back` needs a `const Mat& m`.

You can get a row matrix from a vector:

```
Mat1f m;
vector<float> v1 = {1.f, 1.5f, 2.1f};
vector<float> v2 = {3.f, 3.5f, 4.1f};

Mat temp1(Mat1f(v1).t());
Mat temp2(Mat1f(v2).t());

m.push_back(temp1);
m.push_back(temp2);
```

Comment: ok. how can I convert a vector<float> into a Mat& m (row vector) and push it after that ?